# Audio Broadcasting Live to internet

Tags: iphone, objective-c, audio, broadcast

I am trying to develop an application related to Live Audio Broadcasting on internet.I already seen application like Ustream and ipadio.My query is How they are creating a web address to each users..?Is it a server side coading..?any information please ...? I Implemented AQRecorder.mm class to my application for recording and taking as audio buffers.now i want to send the audio buffers over the internet..Am I do any server side code for create a web address to each users..?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. for this particular case if you want to send audio to the internet you first need to have a website. then create a new folder for that particular user so that the audio can be saved on the server side. then if the user wants to listen to their own recordings the application can just connect to the internet on the server side and obtain the recording.
Let me know if this helps.

Pk